# select first occurrence of numbers from middle of the string

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the following string.

My address is 26854, Apt 556, Livonia, MI 48354

My address is 1899, Suit 1233, Detroit, MI 48114

My address is 268543, Apt 293, Livonia, MI 48386

Output i am expecting is **26854**.

Output i am expecting is **1899**.

Output i am expecting is **268543**.

Answer (score 2):

Use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr('My address is 26854, Apt 556, Livonia, MI 48354', '[0-9]+', 1, 1)
from dual;
```

Comment: what if my string look like 'My address is -26854, Apt 556, Livonia, MI 48354' then this solution is not working. Any idea why it is not working after add '-'?

Comment: I try the following and now it is working.

select regexp_substr('My address is 26854, Apt 556, Livonia, MI 48354', '[-0-9]+', 1, 1)
from dual;

Comment: @MohsinAlvi . . . You would include all the characters that constitute the "number".  If the hyphen could only be at the beginning, it would be `'-?[0-9]+'`.